# VBScript FTP Delete file if exists

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I'm having trouble deleting a file from an FTP server if it exists, below is a really cut down version of my code but usually the inFile is a varible. The code below in theory should delete the file test.txt from the FTP server as it does exist but nothing seems to happens. If I create a local directory with a test.txt file in it and point the inFile at that directory the file deletes fine so I'm assuming it has something to do with remote connections. Any ideas?

```
inFile = "ftp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.txt"

File_Delete(inFile)

Sub File_Delete (inFile)

            dim strProc, objFSO

            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            If objFSO.FileExists(inFile) Then
                            objFSO.DeleteFile infile                                                
            end if

            set objFSO = nothing


end sub
```

Comment: FSO is only for managing local files. Might be able to do some http request using xml object to download files, but not delete. You need some com+ component or something

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, the only other way I might be able to do it is by having the script open ftp.exe then pass the commands through via a text file

Comment: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-ftp-files-from-asp.html